# ARKit : Show object with actual size

Tags: ios, xcode, augmented-reality, scaling, arkit

I am fetching 3d models from server and showing in app.
Everything works fine, except 3d models appears to small on camera as compared to it's actual size.

Here is my code :

```
    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()

    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
          child.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
          child.movabilityHint = .movable
          let light = SCNLight()
          light.type = .ambient
          child.light = light
          child.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
          wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
    }
 self.addChildNode(wrapperNode)
 wrapperNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
```

I also try to set scaling to SCNVector3(1, 1, 1), but that case object gets place on top position(incorrect position).
virtualObjectScene contains by .scn object, which is downloaded from server.

Comment: If you create your own model and upload it to server - You should make some ground rule so that the model uploaded will be displayed correctly on the app. Check the size, pivots and rotation of the model before uploading to server. And after few models, you will develop understanding on how to create the model per app requirement.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408050-scale
From the apple doc, you can found out that when you set child.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1) , the childNode (model) you add to wrapperNode is 0.1 of its actual size.
I don't know which SCNVector3(1, 1, 1) you have tried so sorry if this don't work.

Comment: Hey Quang, I replaced SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1) with SCNVector3(1, 1, 1)  in code. In that case, on placing object it show on very top position, which is incorrect.